# Excel Fomula required, possibly VLOOKUP with SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with multiple sheets for software purchased and software installed.  I am trying to put a formula in the "Purchased" sheet (1) which will perform a look up of a name of a piece of software in the "installed" sheet(2) and calculate the number of installs shown in sheet 2 column C and put the total in Sheet1.  There could be multiple rows showing installs in Sheet 2, which is why I want it to calculate the totals rather than a straight vlookup.
Ideas please :)

In my example data sheet1 C3 is where I want the formula to go, I want it to look for the software name in Sheet 2 and return the total from B2 adding up the multiple installs shown

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYMKP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You want `=COUNTIF` but no-ones going to be able to give you specific formula help unless you show a bit more of the data and what you've tried so far.

It also might be useful to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to avoid people downvoting your question.

---

**Now you've added the example data the C2 formula is:**

`=SUMIF('Software Installed'!A:A,'Purchased software'!A2,'Software Installed'!B:B)`

Comment: Thanks Tim, ive added more detail

Comment: Has that sorted it? If so you might want to follow [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by the term 'purchased' in your example. But from the formula 'C2-B2' in the final column on the first sheet 'Purchased Software' I understand that you somehow need to deduct the purchased software from the installed software which makes no sense to me, but fine if you understand the formula you can easily change it to your needs.

We have one workbook with two sheets, I have named the sheets. 1='Purchased Software' and 2='Software Installed'.

'Software installed' has just the table with raw data, nothing else.

'Purchased software' has the list of unique software products in column A
(look at https://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html, to see how to get a unique list from a list with duplicate values).

Column B has user input, telling us which items are purchased.

Column C has our formula.

Column D deducts the number in Column B (Purchased) from the number in column C (Installed).

The formula: =SUMIFS('Software Installed'!$B$2:$B$6;'Software Installed'!$A$2:$A$6;$A2)
consists of two ranges and the name of the software (also a range as I pointed it to the first column).

'Software Installed'!$B$2:$B$6 = The number of items installed for that software. This can be multipel rows for the same software as in the example with 'Becrypt Enterprise Manager 4'

'Software Installed'!$A$2:$A$6 = The range with software product names

$A2 = The name of the software product

The dollar signs make sure those values are not changed when you copy the formula.

This should give you the result you need.

Koos

[image]